# Manipulation of Word Document using OOXML?

Tags: java, ms-word, openxml

We have a requirement to read Word document and make changes to it with dynamic data from Application & some sections that will be updated by the user directly into the word.
Every time the user wants to fetch data from Application, he will upload the document and merge it.

To be more specific, I looked into option of manipulating the word document by adding meta tags as markers in the ooxml for each section. But i am not able to find any.Is there an option to add meta tags for content, which can act like template markers?

Note: We want to implement this in a Java application.

Comment: You may find http://www.slideshare.net/plutext/document-generation-2012osdcsydney helpful.  You can use content controls to identify/tag block or run level content.

Answer (score 0):

You can use special Java Library: http://poi.apache.org/ Apache POI to manipulate DOC files, but for template you need different system like velocity or freemarker. Or you can just use String replace.